# NO Storage class or type specifier with string array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++-cli, clr

i have a c++ CLR app im creating and i cant declare my string array for some reason.
im using namespace system(not to familiar with it).

the error message says "The declaration has no storage or type specifier"

```
private:

     string[] folderFile = null;
     int selected = 0;
     int begin = 0;
     int end = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of C++ strings, the syntax is:

```
std::string folderFile[length]; // not a pointer, cannot be nullptr
```

To create a pointer to an array of C++ strings, so you can set the length when you create it:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> folderFile; // initially nullptr
```

To create a (tracking reference to a) CLR array of (tracking references to) CLR strings, the syntax is:

```
array<System::String^>^ folderFile;
```

The first two options can only be used in a C++ class (`class` or `struct`), while the last one is only for CLR classes (`ref class`, `value struct` and the like).